# Difference between passing a callback as value and as expanded arrow function

Tags: javascript

When passing a callback, is doing so by value:

```
utility.subscribe(this.callback);
```

not the same as passing it as its expanded form?

```
utility.subscribe(arg => this.callback(arg));
```

I had the understanding that they are equivalent, but encountered a problem when context was needed to be passed together with the callback.

```js
var utility = {
  name: 'utility',
  subscribe(callback) {
    var msgForCallback = 'Hey callback!';
    callback(msgForCallback);
  }
}

var user = {
  name: 'user',
  useSubscriber() {
    utility.subscribe(
      this.callback
    );
  },
  useSubscriberWithArrow() {
    utility.subscribe(
      arg => this.callback(arg)
    );
  },
  callback (arg) {
    console.log(`Context: ${this.name}`);
    console.log(`The utility says: ${arg}`);
  }
}

console.log('\nCall user.useSubscriber();');
user.useSubscriber();
console.log('\nCall user.useSubscriberWithArrow();');
user.useSubscriberWithArrow();
```

I realize that the callback function is a regular function, and that's why the context may be lost. So I tried changing it to an arrow function, but then even the call with an expanded callback loses the context.

```
callback: (arg) => { .. }
```

instead of

```
callback (arg) { .. }
```

```js
var utility = {
  name: 'utility',
  subscribe(callback) {
    var msgForCallback = 'Hey callback!';
    callback(msgForCallback);
  }
}

var user = {
  name: 'user',
  useSubscriber() {
    utility.subscribe(
      this.callback
    );
  },
  useSubscriberWithArrow() {
    utility.subscribe(
      arg => this.callback(arg)
    );
  },
  callback: (arg) => {
    console.log(`Context: ${this.name}`);
    console.log(`The utility says: ${arg}`);
  }
}

console.log('\nCall user.useSubscriber();');
user.useSubscriber();
console.log('\nCall user.useSubscriberWithArrow();');
user.useSubscriberWithArrow();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I guess it is a slightly different question, as I'm also wondering how the code reads/expands the function passed, as a regular function or as an arrow function?

Comment: @Andrew, I've described what is the problem, why this problem occurs...read my answer...everything will be clear to you....

Answer (score 2):

1. To understand what is wrong with your code, you first must understand the difference between `regular function` declaration and `arrow function` declaration. `arrow function's this` is bind to it's environments `this`(i.e. where it is defined).
2. secondly, you've to understand that, function within a `object method` does not point to `'this' of the object`, rather it's point to `global this` i.e. like below:

```
let obj = {
  someMethod() {
    function someFun() {
      // here 'this' points to 'global this'
      // i.e. 'this' does not points to obj
    }
  }
}
```

I guess the above points are clear...

Now, come to your code:

First rewrite `callback` as a `regular function`. don't write it as `arrow`.

I'm providing the code below with some more lines(for debugging purposes):

```
let utility = {
  name: 'utility',  
  subscribe(callback) {
    let msgForCallback = 'Hey callback!';
    callback(msgForCallback);
  }
};


let user = {
  name: 'user',

  useSubscriber() {
    utility.subscribe(this.callback);
  },

  useSubscriberWithArrow() {
    utility.subscribe(arg => this.callback(arg + " With Arrow Huh "));
  },

  callback(arg) {
    console.log('this: ');
    console.log(this);
    console.log("-----------");
    console.log(`Context: ${this.name}`);
    console.log(`The utility says: ${arg}`);
    console.log("__________________________________________________________________________");
  }
};


console.log('\nCall user.useSubscriber();');
user.useSubscriber();

console.log('\nCall user.useSubscriberWithArrow();');
user.useSubscriberWithArrow();
```

**We'll be talking about what is wrong with the code given above.**

**The wrong with the code is user.useSubscriber() won't be able to resolve `this.name` when `callback` is called.**

**Why?**

Note: `user.callback()` is not an `arrow` function, rather it's a regular function and is passed to `utility.subscribe()`. So, it becomes, like the second point I've described above, `function with in object method`, so, the `this` will be bind to `global this`. You may prove it by running the code. the code's output is somewhat like below(I've tested in `node v10.16.*`):

```
Call user.useSubscriber();
this:
Object [global] {
  DTRACE_NET_SERVER_CONNECTION: [Function],
  DTRACE_NET_STREAM_END: [Function],
  DTRACE_HTTP_SERVER_REQUEST: [Function],
  DTRACE_HTTP_SERVER_RESPONSE: [Function],
...
...
-----------
Context: undefined
The utility says: Hey callback!
__________________________________________________________________________

Call user.useSubscriberWithArrow();
this:
{ name: 'user',
  useSubscriber: [Function: useSubscriber],
  useSubscriberWithArrow: [Function: useSubscriberWithArrow],
  callback: [Function: callback] }
-----------
Context: user
The utility says: Hey callback! With Arrow Huh
__________________________________________________________________________
```

I guess, that clears the problem.

**Now, why `user.useSubscriberWithArrow()` works**:

It works cause, remember what I've discussed in the first point - `arrow function is bind to it's environments 'this'(i.e. where it is defined)`. So, you've passed a `arrow` function as `callback`, not `user.callback()` itself, and that `arrow function` is used to call `this.callback()`. And, the `arrow's` `this` is bound to `user`, cause it is defined within `user` object.

I guess that clears your problem. If you've anymore questions ,ask me in the comment...

Comment: Why must `callback` be a regular function? If I define it as an arrow function (before passing it into `subscribe`), shouldn't it get bound to the object's context?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have my own answers. For the first part:

```
utility.subscribe(this.callback);
```

is equivalent to:

```
utility.subscribe(function (arg) {
  console.log(`Context: ${this.name}`);
  console.log(`The utility says: ${arg}`);
});
```

and not:

```
utility.subscribe(arg => {
  console.log(`Context: ${this.name}`);
  console.log(`The utility says: ${arg}`);
});
```

As for the second part, the change would work if the user object were to be a class:

```js
var utility = {
  name: 'utility',
  subscribe(callback) {
    var msgForCallback = 'Hey callback!';
    callback(msgForCallback);
  }
}

var User = class {

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'user';
  }

  useSubscriber() {
    utility.subscribe(
      this.callback
    );
  }

  useSubscriberWithArrow() {
    utility.subscribe(
      arg => this.callback(arg)
    );
  }

  callback = (arg) => {
    console.log(`Context: ${this.name}`);
    console.log(`The utility says: ${arg}`);
  }
}

var user = new User();
console.log('\nCall user.useSubscriber();');
user.useSubscriber();
console.log('\nCall user.useSubscriberWithArrow();');
user.useSubscriberWithArrow();
```